# @awesome-cordova-plugins/file - Invalid Provider for NgModule [object Object]

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Here's the problem, trying to migrate to cap 5 and after it come some change on cordova package, after update and using some of package there error it always showing [object Object]
Here's the import of some cordova package. I used these imports for both page module and ts

```
import { FileTransfer, FileTransferObject } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/file-transfer/ngx';
import { File } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/file/ngx';
```

and then this is the provider on module page

```
@NgModule({
...
providers: [FileTransferObject,File],
...
})
```

when im using this it showing error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: 
R3InjectorError(PdfViewerPageModule)
[[object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object]]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!
```

and somehow when i input the `FileTransferObject` it says another error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 
'PdfViewerPageModule' - 
only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: 
[..., ..., ?[object Object]?]
```

is there any solution or some step that i missing ?

**`UPDATE`**

I already trying to tracing the source of problem is from

```
private transfer: FileTransfer,
```

but still i already tried to add provider from exact same package on module and ts page using this

```
import { FileTransfer, FileTransferObject } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/file-transfer/ngx';
```

bcs i added the `FileTransfer` as Provider is showing

```
Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'PdfViewerPageModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [..., ?[object Object]?]
```

still needed some solution.
Thanks